# Trimming text in a text file using bat

Tags: batch-file

I am running the this command:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig /all^|find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set ip=%%a
goto :IPaddress1
)
:IPaddress1
echo ip1:%ip: =% >>"Z:\Retrievedinfo\untrimmedIP.txt"
```

and I get this result in the untrimmed.txt file:

```
ip1:192.168.111.1(Preferred)
```

What code do I use to trim the "(Preferred)" from the end so that I am left with:

```
ip1:192.168.111.1
```

Comment: Your aim is to just to get the IPv4 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the text to nothing like this:

```
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig /all^|find "IPv4 Address"') do (
    set ip=%%a
    goto :IPaddress1
    )
    :IPaddress1
    set ip=ip1:%ip:(Preferred)=%
    echo %ip: =% >>"Z:\Retrievedinfo\untrimmedIP.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
echo( 
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do (
  set ip=%%b
)
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo( 
echo The Local IPv4 adress is : %ip%
echo The Local IPv4 adress is : %ip% >>"Z:\Retrievedinfo\TrimmedIP.txt"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add `(` to the list of delimiters.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%a in ('ipconfig /all^|find "IPv4 Address"') do set "ip=%%a"
set "ip=%ip:~1%"
```

An alternative to using a substring operation is to use a 2nd FOR /F loop to strip the leading space(s)

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%a in ('ipconfig /all^|find "IPv4 Address"') do for /f %%b in ("%%a") do set "ip=%%b"
```